# findViewById in fragment , how to get view outside onCreateView

Tags: java, android, listview, parsing, adapter

Simple json parsing, but i can't do it cause whenever I would like build it, it crashes, I think it's because of "findViewById".

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    showDrugs(null);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
}
private void showDrugs(String search) {
    ListView lvDrugs = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvDrugs);
    MyRealm myRealm = new MyRealm(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    RealmResults<Drug> drugs = myRealm.getDrugs(search);
    DrugListAdapter adapter = new DrugListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), drugs);
    lvDrugs.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Please clean up the formatting, and ask a specific question in the body of your post. What are you expecting to see happen, and what is the error? Is there a specific line of code you are wondering about?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `showDrugs()` before inflating the view because `getView()` is `null`.

Simplest way is to call `showDrugs()` in  `onViewCreated()`, which is called right after `onCreateView()`, where you can be sure that `getView()` isn't `null`.